# Usrp Full Duplex Operation

Tags: c++, usrp

I have a USRP N200 with WBX daughterboard. I'd need a simple C/C++
program that can simultaneously receive and transmit. but I can't find It.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the examples [that come with UHD](https://github.com/EttusResearch/uhd/tree/master/host/examples). There's the [txrx loopback example](https://github.com/EttusResearch/uhd/blob/master/host/examples/txrx_loopback_to_file.cpp) which does exactly that.

In essence, it's not complicated:

1. spawn a thread for receiving and one for transmitting. This is optional, but it will make your system much less prone to receive sample over- or transmit sample underruns.
2. create an `rx_streamer` and a `tx_streamer`
3. In the RX thread, call the `rx_streamer->recv()` method repeatedly in the TX thread, `tx_streamer->send()` method repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But this example create one thread for TX and don't create a thread for RX. so I think after Transmit a packet, I can receive. and This means Half-Duplex. Is this True?

Comment: @user1210922: no, this is not true. It's full duplex, and there's a thread for receiving and one thread for transmitting, like I explained. The `transmit_worker` function runs in the thread `transmit_thread`, whereas the `recv_to_file` function runs in the main thread.